# Making a vertical table using multidimensional array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I've used a multidimensional to create a table,however when I run it it seems that the table keeps going horizontally, how can I make it line up vertical when it is ran?

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    int firstarray[][]={{1,2,3,4,5}
                        ,{6,7,8,9,10}};
    int secondarray[][]={{30,31,32,33,}
                        ,{43},{4,5,6}};

    System.out.println("This is the first array");
    display(firstarray);

    System.out.println("This is the second array");
    display(secondarray);
}
public static void display (int x[][]){
    for(int row=0;row<x.length;row++){
        for(int column=0;column<x[row].length;column++){
            System.out.print(x[row][column]+"\t");
        }
    }   
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inner Loop prints out each column that make each line for you, so at the end of each line you have to use `System.out.println` to go to the next line which is related to Outer loop. In better scene, if you want to have new line , before reading new column that make next line, you have to use System.out.println`

Hope this sample helps you to learn it better

Code:

```
       int a[][] = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}};

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("---> It is going to read colmuns in order to make a line");
            for (int j = 0; j < a[0].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(a[i][j]+" ");
            }
            System.out.println("-->It is going to make a new next line");
        }
```

Output:

```
---> It is going to read colmuns in order to make a line 1 2 3 4 5 -->It is going to make a new next line
---> It is going to read colmuns in order to make a line 6 7 8 9 10 -->It is going to make a new next line
```

Answer (score 0):

Break each line after your inner loop:

```
for (int row=0; row<x.length; row++) {
   for (int column=0; column<x[row].length; column++) {
      System.out.print(x[row][column]+"\t");
   }
   System.out.println(); // Break current line
}
```